# Unable to make my script keep clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've created a script using `node.js` in association with `puppeteer` to click on ***`more`*** button located at the bottom of a webpage to dig out all the headlines from it's landing page.

The thing is when I execute my script, It only clicks once and then quits. How can I keep clicking on that button until there is no more button to be clicked, meaning all the links are revealed?

- [The link to that site](https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football/Championship/Transfer+News)

My attempt so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football/Championship/Transfer+News", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.waitForSelector("[class^='hl_more']");
    await page.click("[class^='hl_more']");
    await browser.close();
})();
```

As I'm new to `node.js` and `puppeteer`, I can't understand as to how I can define a loop to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I often do in situations like this is use a `try catch` block to check for an elements visibility using `waitForSelector` and using a very short timeout. You need the `try catch` block because `waitForSelector` will eventually timeout when that **more** button is no longer visible. This is also why you will need to use a short, specific timeout as you don't want your code to pause for 30 seconds (the default timeout) while trying to find the component.

So what I would do is this:

```
// This method checks if an element is visible and times out cleanly after 2 seconds if it is not displayed
const isElementVisible = async (page, cssSelector) => {
  try {
    await page.waitForSelector(cssSelector, { timeout: 2000 });
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

(async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football/Championship/Transfer+News", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  let moreDisplayed = await isElementVisible(page, '[class^="hl_more"]');
  while (moreDisplayed) {
    await page.click('[class^="hl_more"]');
    moreDisplayed = await isElementVisible(page, '[class^="hl_more"]');
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: This is the `a.hl_more.bg_tween:not(.nfloading)` selector that should be replaced with the current one to do the trick flawlessly. Btw, something to put into the parentheses `catch () ` for the script to work. I suggested this for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a loop of the command that makes click, e.g.:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football/Championship/Transfer+News", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.waitForSelector("[class^='hl_more']");
    while (1) { // This one
        await page.click("[class^='hl_more']");
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

[Various loop types in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code).